# last added object in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbHandlerPointerNote ,selectQuery , -1, &prepareStmtNote, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)                     {
            while (sqlite3_step(prepareStmtNote) == SQLITE_ROW)

        {
            NSString *noteName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(prepareStmtNote, 0)];
            [_notesArray addObject:noteName];
            int noteid =sqlite3_column_int(prepareStmtNote, 1);
            [_noteidArray  addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",noteid]];
            NSString *noteDate = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(prepareStmtNote,2)];
            [_notesDate addObject:noteDate];
            // arrObj is a mutable arr

        }
    }
```

Above is how I added objects to the `note_id` array.

Here is how I am trying to get the last object:

```
_savedNoteid1=[[_modleClass.noteidArray lastObject]intValue];
```

but it is not working correctly.  How do I get the last object in the array?

Comment: Define 'not working correctly'.

Comment: just NSLog your array before trying to access any objects inside. In this way, you can see if the array has the desired objects or not. `NSLog(@"%@", _modleClass.noteidArray);`

Comment: @Inafziger Hard to say what the OP is trying to do -- the question is full of holes. We don't know what type `_savedNoteid1` is.

Comment: _savedNoteid1 is the integer value...

Comment: @user1997077: Please let us know what your program is doing wrong when you try to access the last object in the array.

Answer (score 2):

> i want to get what the object added to last to the array how is it possible.....

If all you want is to access the last object in an instance of NSArray (or NSMutableArray), you can simply use the `-lastObject` method:

```
id item = [someArray lastObject];
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are using now is very close, just take off the last part of it (intValue):

```
_savedNoteid1=[_modleClass.noteidArray lastObject];
```

Comment: _savedNoteid is the inteer value...thats why i covert to integer...